# Debian 10 cannot open display:

Tags: x11, xorg, display

I have a Debian 10 system with a desktop environment installed and running. When I open a terminal and try to run any GUI application , such as gedit, from the command line, it fails to open with the following messages:

```
# gedit
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:3575): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:26:48.311: cannot open display:
```

This happens with any user, not just root.

I have tried running the following based on suggestions to no avail:

```
 export DISPLAY=:0
 export DISPLAY=:1
 export DISPLAY=:2
 export DISPLAY=:3
 export DISPLAY=:4
 export DISPLAY=:5
 export DISPLAY=:6




xhost +
```

Anyone have any idea whats wrong here?

EDIT:

If I run `export DISPLAY=:0` as a normal user, then the normal user can run GUI programs from the command line, however whenever I try the same with root it fails with the messages:

```
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:3609): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:33:16.307: cannot open display: :0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The display belongs to the user. So, if you want to allow another user to draw on it (think of it as a printer) you have to grant permissions.

There are many ways to do that, but the simplest is probably to open the graphic terminal and run:

```
$ xhost +
```

That will allow connections to the server from other users.

Then, from the other user you can run:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0
```

It could be another display, such as :1 ...

If you want to avoid those two steps, you can `ssh` into the other user, with the -X flag (that forwards the display):

```
$ ssh -X -l other_user localhost
```

Comment: I have already tried `xhost +` to no avail.

Comment: You have to do both things, in two different places. The `xhost +` as the _normal_ user and then, from _the other user's shell_ the `export DISPLAY...`. To check, just run `xeyes`. To be sure of the display you want to export for the second user, you can do `echo $DISPLAY` from the _normal_ user's shell.

Answer (score -1):

I just added switch `-E` after `sudo` command.

for example:

```
sudo -E gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question posed  by the original poster and doesn't explain how it solves the problem.